# Deploy yeoman angular-fullstack project to Azure

Tags: angularjs, git, azure, yeoman, azure-web-app-service

How would would you deploy the output of the [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) Yeoman generator to Azure? The generator produces output like this, i.e. two folders - `client` and `server`.

```
├── client
│   ├── app                 - All of our app specific components go in here
│   ├── assets              - Custom assets: fonts, images, etc…
│   ├── components          - Our reusable components, non-specific to to our app
│
├── e2e                     - Our protractor end to end tests
│
└── server
    ├── api                 - Our apps server api
    ├── auth                - For handling authentication with different auth strategies
    ├── components          - Our reusable or app-wide components
    ├── config              - Where we do the bulk of our apps configuration
    │   └── local.env.js    - Keep our environment variables out of source control
    │   └── environment     - Configuration specific to the node environment
    └── views               - Server rendered views
```

I'd like to deploy this to Microsoft Azure, and ideally using Git deploy. How would I go about that?

#### Update

Here's what the deployment file structure looks like in Azure.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the short version:

1. Create a new blank Web App in Azure.
2. In the Deployment options, select 'Set up continuous deployment'.
3. Select 'Local Git Repository'.

This will give you a `Git Remote` for the blank azure Web App to allow you to push to it. Which means you can do this:

```
git remote add azure [URL for remote repository]
git push azure master
```

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/) is the longer version (it is for a node app - but the same concepts apply).

Comment: I've tried that a couple of times - I just get a 500 error and nothing displays, just a blank page. There seems to be something else required when deploying the angular-fullstack project.

Comment: @StuartHallows You may need to do a bit of re-configuration. I notice that angular-fullstack uses mongodb - this will obviously not work out of the box on Azure. There is some information on mongodb on Azure here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/windows-azure/

Comment: I have Mongo set up, that's not the issue. It's the fact that there's a server and client folder and I don't think Azure is dealing with this. Normally Azure would detect a Node app was deployed and set up some config. That's not happening in this case and I don't know how to set this up.

Comment: You have to create a re-write rule on your web.config , But I still figuring out the right set up